# How can I enable eval() in Boomla

Tags: eval, content-security-policy, boomla

I want to host a website on Boomla where the user can enter program code and a client-side compiler compiles it. The compiler uses `eval()` internally, which I cannot work around, so I absolutely need it enabled.

The default Content-Security-Policy rules do not allow eval, and it is not allowed to enable it with `.ContentSecurityPolicy` either.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the Content-Security-Policy rule `script-src 'unsafe-eval'`.

---

*Original answer:* Correct, it's impossible right now. Let me get back within a day, I have already been considering to enable it on demand (make it configurable).